# Execution failed for task: Transform classes and resources with proguard when tried to run Espresso UI test

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-espresso

I try to run espresso tests, but always get next Gradle warning:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDevDebugAndroidTest'.

This is my Gradle configurations.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.txt'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.txt'
            testProguardFile 'proguard-test.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

    }
```

and proguar-test.pro

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontwarn
```

Other tests are ok, but tests that contain Espresso-methods like `onView()` can't be run. But all tests pass in Jenkins. What is wrong about that?

Comment: Is it not because `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` should be `false` in `debug` mode ?

Comment: Btw you have twice `minifyEnabled` with different settings in `debug`

Comment: I also have this problem but I need to have have `useProguard ` set to true for compiling with play services 11.8.0. :(

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Delete duplicate `minifyEnabled true` in `debug` build type.
2. Set `useProguard false` in `debug` build type.

Hope it helps!